# Can't enter reboot mode after encountering "Started Hold until boot process finishes up"

Tags: ram, reboot, memory-usage

I've encountered the classical "Started Hold until boot process finishes up" due to memory fulling. I've followed the guides trying to enter reboot mode to remove some files, but when i turn on the machine and press "esc" the screen won't activate. Is there any solution to this issue? I'm running the version 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver). This the first time I've encountered the issue.

Comment: There is insufficient information here to even guess at an answer. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you're running (1) the hardware specs of your computer (2) whether this is a new issue or one that has appeared after a recent update. With this, it *may* be possible to propose solutions 

Comment: I'm running the version 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver). This the first time I've encountered the issue. And I haven't updated the version for some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.On the boot window, select the advanced option for Ubuntu to enter into the recovery mode.

2.Once you are on the recovery mode, select the root option to enter into a terminal environment.

3.Press enter, then change the directory to the following address:

> cd /home/user_name/Downloads.

4.Enter `du -s * | sort -nr | head -n10` to list top 10 largest directories.

5.Glance at the short list and enter `rm -r .\file_to_be_removed`.

6.`control-d` to return to the recovery mode, then resume the normal boot.

Once you finished up, you will be able to log into your account without any trouble. Good luck!

(OR)

*Simple way Remove your Drive connect to another system delete some files and connect it to your system*

Comment: As I've mentioned, the problem comes from not being able to enter recovery mode due to black screen.

Comment: Okay , Simple way Remove your Drive connect to another system delete some files and connect it to your system

Comment: Yes sure -ChanganAuto. We can try booting live session.